# Powershell script not getting all information needed from Office 365 (MsolService)

Tags: powershell, office365

I am trying to get certain information from our Office 365 but not getting all the information required.

Below is my script I use:

```
Get-MsolUser -All | select DisplayName, LastPasswordChangeTimeStamp, LastLogonTime, PrimaryEmailAddress | Export-CSV UserList.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

The information I am getting from the above script is only the display name last password change.  For the `LastLogonTime` and `PrimaryEmailAddress` I get nothing.

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: I know you can get lastlogontime from `Get-MailboxStatistics`. I am not sure how reliable that is. As far as the primary email, you can use the `ProxyAddresses` field: `Select-Object @{n="PrimaryEmailAddress";e={$_.ProxyAddresses.where{$_ -clike "SMTP:*"} -creplace "SMTP:"}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Last logon time can be retrieved from Get-MailboxStatistics but it shows last accessed Exchange mailbox alone. It doesn't track other Office 365 services. You can try below code for your requirement.

```
$Result=""  
$Output=@()
Get-mailbox -All | foreach{
$UPN=$_.UserPrincipalName
$DisplayName=$_.DisplayName
$PrimaryEmailAddress=$_.ProxyAddresses.where{$_ -clike "SMTP:*"} -creplace "SMTP:"
$LastPwdChange=$_.LastPasswordChangeTimeStamp
$LastLogonTime=(Get-MailboxStatistics -Identity $upn).lastlogontime
$Result= @{'DisplayNme'=$DisplayName;'LastLogonTime'=$LastLogonTime;'PrimaryEmailAddress'=$PrimaryEmailAddress;'LastPwdChange'=$LastPwdChange}
$Output= New-Object PSObject -Property $Result 
$Output | Select-Object DisplayName,LastLogonTime,PrimaryEmailAddress,LastPwdChange | Export-CSV UserList.csv -Notype -Append
}
```